# Imagemagick: How to reduce size for annimated GIF with big static areas?

Tags: image, imagemagick, compression, gif, animated-gif

I created an animated `output.gif` from a screen capture that ends up being 89MB uncompressed. Half of the GIF is static but it would be best keeping it together rather than an image + a GIF containing the moving part.

Using Imagemagick and the following command I manage to reduce its size down to 18.1MB:

```
convert output.gif -coalesce -fuzz 3% +dither -layers Optimize compressed.gif
```

Increasing the percent produces much smaller size results but the quality is compromised.

Is there an option you suggest using for yielding a much better file size reduction without compromising on quality given that this GIF contains a large static non animated area?

**UPDATE** I'm using Ubuntu for this and here is my full workflow:

1. Use [Kazam](https://launchpad.net/kazam) to screen capture exactly what I need so no need for editing of any kind.
2. Use the command `ffmpeg -i input.avi output.mp4` to convert to mp4.
3. Make directory for the frames `mkdir frames`.
4. Generate intermediary images `ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -r 25 'frames/frame-%04d.png'`.
5. Go to frames `cd frames`.
6. Generate the GIF from the images `convert -delay 4 -loop 0 *.png output.gif`.
7. Optimize and compress the GIF to reduce file size `convert output.gif -coalesce -fuzz 3% +dither -layers Optimize compressed.gif`

Comment: Would an `avi` be acceptable - that would be miles smaller. You could also try removing `-fuzz 3% +dither` and replacing it with `-colors 32` or maybe `-colors 63` and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell! thanks for your reply. I have AVI originally but it is 1.7GB or so .. I am updating my question using the full workflow.

Comment: See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_opt/ for gif animation optimization. Use one common color map for all frames. See -remap for that at https://imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#remap_common

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to reduce the size of the GIF is to put as many frames as possible in "combine" mode. These frames only contain what has changed from the previous frame and this can be quite small, but this may require that all the frames be encoded with the very same colormap, and that identical parts are truly identical (no fuzziness, no random encoding artifacts). Gimp can do that but other utilities specialized in GIF processing can also do that (Gifsicle perhaps)?

Also, the animated GIF of a screen capture doesn't need to be 25fps, 10fps is more than enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! can you please also provide the commands you'd suggest that might help improve making the file smaller? It may seem obvious but it is not for me ... I have shown my entire workflow so what should I do on top of that? for example which command and options I'd need for using `gifslice`?

Comment: The main criteria is **identical parts are truly identical (no fuzziness, no random encoding artifacts).** Since your first output in an AVI file (compressed video), this is likely not true. What you can try is load your GIF in Gimp, and try `Filters>Animations>Optimize (for GIF)` and export again. Maybe there are still enough common things to optimize.